# How to Inject Prototype bean in Mockito

Tags: spring, mockito

I am using `InjectMocks` and `Spy` annotations for injecting a prototype bean.

However the inject bean behaves like singleton bean. Is there any way to inject a prototype scoped bean in Mockito?

I am running JUnit with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` and init mocks using `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`.

Comment: If you use @Spy, which instance of your prototype bean would you be spying on, if there were more than one? You are declaring one variable but want it to act as several, do I get this right?

Comment: I am using Spy as the dependency is private variable. And yes, I am declaring 1 variable and I am expecting Mockito to inject new instance of bean each time it is referred.

Comment: No way of doing that that I know of, expect manually, of course. I doubt that's a real demand for that in a typcial mockito setting, where you want to call `do...when...` or `verify` on the spy, which is impossible if the `@Spy` variable is just some kind of template instead of an actual spy.

Answer (score 4):

That's because Mockito creates your injected objects at compile time.
If you want a prototype-like behavior, you need to switch to using answers.

For example, assume that your Spring application has a prototype bean called Foo and your code is doing something like this multiple times:

```
ctx.getBean("Foo");
```

Since Foo is a prototype, every time getBean() is called, a new instance of Foo is returned by Spring.

Now, in your Mockito test you mocked the ctx to spoof the getBean() and return your own pre-configured instance of Foo.

if you set up your test like below, no matter how many times your code calls ctx.getBean(), the same instance of Foo will be returned:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
decorateFoo(foo);
when(ctx.getBean("Foo")).thenReturn(foo);
```

This is how you can achieve a prototype-like behavior in your test:

```
when(ctx.getBean("Foo")).then(new FooAnswer());

private class FooAnswer implements Answer<Foo> {
    @Override
    public Foo answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
                return new Foo(); // and configure as needed
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont get bean from context. I have used Autowire annotation.